# ASP.NET app longer on one machine than another (in IIS)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

I have an ASP.NET app running in IIS. The first time a call to the application is made, it can sometimes take extremely long (e.g. 80 seconds), whereas the second time it's very quick

I know this has to do with the app first starting and possibly needing to gather resources etc. However, the problem is that I can run the same identical app on another machine and the load time for the first call is significantly less.

So I'm wondering what factors on the machine would affect this load time?

Thanks for any assistance

Comment: Are the specs of both machines identical? That would be a factor for a longer start time if it wasn't the case..

Comment: What I was getting at is that one machine may have less memory, a slower/faulty hard drive etc. I would think that would be the most likely cause of any difference in startup times.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with Steve's comment. FYI this slow response on initial request will happen every time the app pool has been idle for a while too. You can combat this by disabling the app pool from shutting down when idle. I think the default is 20 mins, this is a setting in IIS.

Then you will only suffer the problem every time the app pool recycles. You can stop this happening but I don't advise it. Interesting article on this here http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2013/04/06/why-is-the-iis-default-app-pool-recycle-set-to-1740-minutes.aspx Recycling the app pool every now and again protects you from memory leaks. However you can pro actively spin up the app pool by setting up a scheduled task that runs a batch file to make a request to the website on detection of an app pool recycle.

This ensures that your site is always spinning and good to go for every request.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET only compiles when the page is requested for the first time. This means that on first load the page is being compiled and then displayed. This can be solved by following the precompile instructions from Microsoft.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227972%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

EDIT: I realized that I didn't answer the question that you were really asking.

There are a few things that could affect the first load:

1) The browser you are using may not be as efficient at displaying the type of content on the page (assuming different browsers).

2)If the machines aren't running on the same internet connection(and even if they are speeds vary between wifi/ethernet) this could be affecting the overall speed.

3)The specs on the machines themselves can be making a difference, browsers still take up resources to run, and as such a faster computer could display quicker (although it wouldn't make a giant difference).

4)You said the app was running on IIS, but you didn't specify whether it was a local (test) server or a deployed server. If it's local the specs of the machine again come into play, and in a giant way. Booting an IIS server, deploying the app and then displaying pages (what happens when you click run in VS or similar) can take very different amounts of time depending on the machine.